# Format Value on mouse hover in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, code-formatting

I have looked at various documentation and similar questions on here, but cannot seem to find the particular solution. Apologies if I have missed anything obvious or have repeated this question!

As a bit of background info, I have implemented a graph using the Chart.js plugin and passed in the required data from a database. This is all working correctly and is fine.

My problem is I need to display the data in the tooltips as formatted data aka. as numeric with %. As an example, one of my data from database is 0.99232. Whilst I know and understand that I can format it before I pass the value to the graph, I want the "%" symbol to be also displayed on the graph.

How can I change the one on the left to read as the one on the right?
[Image of what I am looking for here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVwnR.png)

The tooltip I tried using is as follows:

```
    tooltips: 
    {
        callbacks: 
        {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) 
            {
               return Number(tooltipItem).toFixed(2) + "%"     
            }
        },
    }
```

However when I try this it displays as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqRhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip item is NOT a number but an object. See here, in the doc, how it is:

- (v3) https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-context
- (v2) https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface

I assume you are using version 2 (based on your config), you could try:

```
tooltips: 
{
    callbacks: 
    {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) 
        {
           const title = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
           const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
           const value = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index]; 
           return title + ': ' + Number(value).toFixed(2) + "%";    
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This worked! What if I want to add the title in front so for example "Remainder" or "Investment" based on what the user is hovering?

Comment: I have updated the answer above adding the label before the percentage